# pointer type operator VS const bool operator precedence

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct a_struct {
    int64_t* le_int;
    bool not_ok;

    a_struct() : le_int{ new int64_t(0) }, not_ok{ false } {}
    ~a_struct() { delete le_int; }

    operator bool() const {
        return !not_ok;
    }

    operator int64_t* () {
        return le_int;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    a_struct s;
    s.not_ok = true;
    if (!s)//<-
        std::cout << "o no." << std::endl;

    else if (s.not_ok)
        std::cout << "waddu heck?" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this example the `!s` resolution prefers the `int64_t*()` operator over the const `bool()` operator.

Why?

Comment: I notice that if I change the signature to `operator int64_t* const ()`, it prefers the `operator bool`. Apparently prefers favoring non-`const` member functions on a non-`const` object to converting to a `bool` instead of an `int64_t*`?

Comment: It also works with a non-const `bool()` operator but I can't have the pointer type operator non-const (because reasons).

Comment: Well, you could then add your own `bool operator!() const`, although it definitely feels like there should be a way to just say "no, use `operator bool` here when you convert to `bool`.

Comment: `bool operator!() const` This is what I was actually looking for :-) Thanks.

Comment: I believe the unary `!` implies an explicit cast to `bool`.  It can be used on any type convertible to bool.  As such, `operator bool` is not a better mach than `operator int64_t*`.

Comment: If you really want to *force* the `bool` operator to be called, then just be explicit about that call, eg: `if (!(bool)s)` or `if (!static_cast<bool>(s))` or `if (!s.operator bool())`.  Or use a temporary variable: `bool b = s; if (!b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your object s is not const, it prefers the non-const way of calling the type cast operator. So, removing the const from your bool type cast operator does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

This is the "initialization by conversion function" case for overload resolution: http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.conv

Both conversion functions are candidates because both are non-explicit and their return types are implicitly convertible to `bool`. Overload resolution is then performed with the object expression `s` as the argument, and the implied object parameter of the conversion functions as the parameters. The implied object parameter has type `T` *cv* `&`, where `T` is the class.

Binding `T&` to `T` is better than binding `T const&` to `T`. This is one of the rules by which implicit conversion sequences are ranked. http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6

Note that there is a tie-breaker rule involving the return types of the conversion functions. Such tie-breaker rules are only considered after ranking of implicit conversion sequences for each parameter fails to yield a best viable function on account of the fact that every parameter's implicit conversion sequence is neither better nor worse than the implicit conversion sequence for the corresponding parameter of the other function. Thus, only if both conversion functions have the same cv-qualification (resulting in identical implicit conversion sequences for the implied object parameter), the tie-breaker is reached. http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2.2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have a guarantee that the `bool()` operator will be selected (over the pointer-type one) if I set it non-const ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle Yes. See the tie-breaker rule. A `bool` to `bool` conversion is better than `int64_t*` to `bool`.